# %2f instead of slash in ReturnUrl

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, model-view-controller

I have a MVC 4 website which has a log-in mechanism as follows:

I have 2 pages for which you must be logged in to access them.

If you click on one of them and you're not logged in it adds the following to the URL: /sign-in?ReturnUrl=/somepage/ . However for the other page it adds  ~/sign-in?ReturnUrl=%2fpagename and it breaks my redirect.

As a solution I modified the url with pushstate and replaced %2f with / and it works. But it only works for browsers that support HTML5.

I checked the web.config for any usual problems (Deny users ="*" and key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" and others) but everything seems fine.

Also the redirect works fine on localhost on all browsers but on the server(azure) it only works for Chrome and Firefox, not for IE9+.

Comment: And what is the question? How are you composing this URL? (hint: unexpected escaping is going to be being done by the code that composes the url; if we can't see that, we can't really comment) Also: wouldn't a *query-string* make this a lot simpler?

Comment: From my understanding ReturnUrl is composed automatically. The question is how come on one page ReturnUrl is composed with '/' and the other with %2f? Because replacing %2f with / works on the server, but only on browsers that support html5.

Comment: Composed automatically *how*? Where is this composed automatically? Again: to emphasize:convention would be for this to be `~/sign-in?ReturnUrl=...`, and there it is **correct** to encode the `/` to `%2f` to yield `?ReturnUrl=%2fpagename`

Comment: The website uses Forms Authentification. `/sign-in?ReturnUrl=/somepage/`  is the corect url, after the users logs in, it redirects him to `somepage`. If the url is   `/sign-in?ReturnUrl=%2fsomepage%2f` the redirect no longer works. It's actually the same problem as my other question posted here but now I found the cause and asked another time with the purpose of being more concise.

Comment: in addition to suddenly changing your mind about what the URL is, you're missing the point: `/sign-in?ReturnUrl=/somepage/` is **incorrect**; it is **expected** and **correct** that query-string values are encoded; the **correct** url is the one with the `%2f`; here's the line of code from ASP.NET MVC that *encodes it*: (SiteAdmin.cs, line 227): `redirectUrl += "?" + ReturnUrlQueryString + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl);` (where `ReturnUrlQueryString` is a `const` of `"ReturnUrl"`). So: where-ever you're getting your url from, a: it isn't MVC, and b: it is wrong

Comment: For completeness: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("/somepage/")` returns `"%2fsomepage%2f"`

Comment: It's not in the solution of the project, I searched. The project was not done by me. So if the URL containing %2f is correct, how come it does not work in IE and works only in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: to answer that I'd need to use fiddler, the debugger, and various other things. Random question: what version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? This is entirely speculation, but I wonder if this is simply a legacy bug that has been fixed for years, but which is biting you because you're using an old old version of MVC

Comment: The project is using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Umbraco 6 on top of it.

Comment: It seems very odd that this would be the first time you would mention Umbraco. Sounds like an Umbraco bug, then...

Comment: I don't know why they chose Umbraco but it's really useless in this project. I'm pretty sure it's an IE problem but only on the server side. The url with `%2f` works on localhost on all browsers but on the Azure server it works only in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Which is why Fiddler traces of all 3 would seem necessary. If I was to guess, I expect that Chrome and Firefox are **fixing** the broken url, issuing a correct url instead of the one in the code, and IE is treating the value as-is, expecting the url to be correct. The only way to know for sure is by sniffing the HTTP traffic, hence Fiddler.

Comment: A colleague fixed it. It was doing another redirect in one of the controllers. So in the end it was double encoding the URL: %202fpagename%202f.

Answer (score 1):

It was doing another redirect in one of the controllers. So in the end it was double encoding the URL: `%202fpagename%202f` .